# Pyenv install python version not responding

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, pyenv

I'm building a docker image based on `nvidia/cuda:11.6.0-devel-ubuntu20.04` trying to install two python versions `3.7.4` and `3.9.10` with `pyenv`. The first one is installed perfectly but the second one hungs i.e. it takes forever to install. Not only that, if you run with the `--verbose` flag, the installation of `3.9.10` hangs at different points. For instance, last time stopped at `Compiling '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9/wave.py'...` and before that at `Compiling '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9/wsgiref/util.py'...`. It is not the first time this happens, on different operating systems and different python versions. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: What's the operating system of the host machine?

Comment: running `uname -a` on the host returns `Linux SECRET_HOSTNAME 5.8.2-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 18:38:22 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`